# How can I filter the events in Google Analytics using the new calculated metrics feature?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events

I'm using this formula to get the conversion rate (and yes I know about Goals Conversion rate but they use unique events for that)

```
{{Total Events}} / {{Sessions}}
```

I want to pass a parameter to the total events part, so that I can limit it to only a specific event category.

It's a really cool feature but I just can't find any documentation about this.